# LinQ result into List

Tags: c#, .net

I have following class as list;

```
class list_TA
{
    public DateTime SAMPLE_TIME { get; set; }
    public string WAIT_CLASS { get; set; }
    public double COUNT { get; set; }

    public list_TA(DateTime SAMPLE_TIME, string WAIT_CLASS,double COUNT)
    {
        this.SAMPLE_TIME = SAMPLE_TIME;
        this.WAIT_CLASS = WAIT_CLASS;
        this.COUNT = COUNT;
    }
}

//SECOND PART

                 var test = listASH
                          .Select(g => new
                          {
                              SAMPLE_TIME = statiClass.By15Seconds(Convert.ToDateTime(g.SAMPLE_TIME)),
                              WAIT_CLASS = g.WAIT_CLASS,
                              COUNT = 0,
                          }).GroupBy(x => new { x.SAMPLE_TIME, x.WAIT_CLASS })
                          .Select(y => new
                          {
                              SAMPLE_TIME = y.Key.SAMPLE_TIME,
                              WAIT_CLASS = y.Key.WAIT_CLASS,
                              COUNT = Math.Round(y.Count() / 15.0, 2),
                          });
```

What i want is loading linq result into list_TA. However below code doesn't work and it gives the following error;

```
 List<list_TA> lst = (List<list_TA>)test.ToList();
```

The Error;

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: System.DateTime SAMPLE_TIME, string WAIT_CLASS, double COUNT>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<vodaMon.list_TA>'
```

Converting ToList(); didn't work.

Comment: Your `new` construction creates instances of anonymous class, but not instances of your class `list_TA`. It should be `new list_TA { ... }`, not `new { ... }`

Comment: Error is: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'SAMPLE_TIME' of 'list_TA.list_TA(DateTime, string, double)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `new list_TA` instead of anynomous type also:
When you instantiate list_TA, it requires DateTime SAMPLE_TIME, string WAIT_CLASS,double COUNT passed as a parameter. In order to solve this, introduce parameterless constructor.

```
 public class list_TA
{
    public DateTime SAMPLE_TIME { get; set; }
    public string WAIT_CLASS { get; set; }
    public double COUNT { get; set; }

    public list_TA()
    {

    }

    public list_TA(DateTime SAMPLE_TIME, string WAIT_CLASS, double COUNT) 
    {
        this.SAMPLE_TIME = SAMPLE_TIME;
        this.WAIT_CLASS = WAIT_CLASS;
        this.COUNT = COUNT;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The anonymous class cannot be implicitly converted to any other type.

you need to use `new list_TA` instead of `new`

add default constructor to your `list_TA` class and use the code below

```
  .Select(y => new list_TA
  {
      SAMPLE_TIME = y.Key.SAMPLE_TIME,
      WAIT_CLASS = y.Key.WAIT_CLASS,
      COUNT = Math.Round(y.Count() / 15.0, 2),
  });
```

or

```
  .Select(y => new list_TA (
      y.Key.SAMPLE_TIME,
      y.Key.WAIT_CLASS,
      Math.Round(y.Count() / 15.0, 2)
   ));
```

Comment: Error is: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'SAMPLE_TIME' of 'list_TA.list_TA(DateTime, string, double)'

Comment: your list_TA needs default constructor. check my answer to see the difference

Answer (score 2):

You can select list_TA in the LINQ like:

```
var test = listASH
                          .Select(g => new
                          {
                              SAMPLE_TIME = statiClass.By15Seconds(Convert.ToDateTime(g.SAMPLE_TIME)),
                              WAIT_CLASS = g.WAIT_CLASS,
                              COUNT = 0,
                          }).GroupBy(x => new { x.SAMPLE_TIME, x.WAIT_CLASS })
                          .Select(y => new list_TA
                          {
                              SAMPLE_TIME = y.Key.SAMPLE_TIME,
                              WAIT_CLASS = y.Key.WAIT_CLASS,
                              COUNT = Math.Round(y.Count() / 15.0, 2),
                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Error is: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'SAMPLE_TIME' of 'list_TA.list_TA(DateTime, string, double)'